# Solving $|z-3| \leq|z-1-i|$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I was trying to solve graphicly: $$|z-3| \leq |z-1-i|$$

I plugged x and y in proper places as real componenets of the comlex number yielding in the end $-4x+2y+7 \leq0$

this might be tackled if
first eqauted to $0$ hence: $y=2x-3.5$

I need to sketch it also and I suppose that it should be all values which are under the graph of $y=2x-3.5$  on the gauss plane?

Comment: Note: Geometrically your equation says that $z$ is closer to one point in the plane than to another, or that the two points are equidistant from $z$. So you should expect the plane to be divided by the perpendicular bisector of the line joining $3$ and $1+i$ - the inequality tells you which side of the bisector $z$ is and whether the bisector itself is included. You should therefore be able to sketch a diagram to check your solution.

Comment: Your approach is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the sketching part: Note that the inequality, viewed geometrically, is satisfied by precisely the points $P$ such that the distance from $P$ to $(3,0)$ is $\le$ the distance from $P$ to $(1,1)$.

Draw the perpendicular bisector $\ell$ of the line segment that joins $(3,0)$ and $(1,1)$. Our points are the points on or "below" line $\ell$.

Comment: do I need to find the line equation of said $l$?

Comment: So, specifically, the "$<$" part is satisfied in the component of the complement of the line containing $(3,0)$. This is a very nice illustration, with an extremely intuitive feel. Very nice indeed. +1.

Comment: You found it (another way). And it is correct, for you can note the slope is right, and it goes through the midpoint  $(2,1/2)$.

Comment: as far as a tester is conerned, is it enough for instacne that I proceed to $$(x-3)^2 +y^2 \leq (x-1)^2 +(y-1)^2$$ than draw what you said?

Comment: your exp is indeed the therotical base as for why we do it as it is...I also understand that for $0$ , $2x-3.5$ is the anwser and for $< 0$, it is everything that below that graph that is the answer

Comment: Yes, for equality of distances we are on the line $\ell$ whose equation you found by a calculation of norms.  In complex variables, a geometric viewpoint is often useful.

Comment: thanks for the insight on how this works

Comment: You are welcome. In dealing with complex variables, there will be continued interaction between geometric insight and complex number "algebra."